# Haar integral invariance against inversion

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group, and $\omega$ is a left-invariant volume form over $G$ such that.

$$\int_{G}\omega = 1$$

with respect to the orientation determined by $\omega$. If I define

$$\int_{G}f(g)dg:=\int_{G}f\omega$$

for every continuous real-valued function $f\colon G\to \mathbb{R}$, the map $f\mapsto\int_{G}f(g)dg$ is called the Haar integral. I need to prove that 
$$\int_{G}f(g^{-1})dg=\int_{G}f(g)dg$$ for any continuous function $f$. I have made some attempts without success. First, I tried to use the modular function $c\colon G\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $R_{g}^{*}\omega = c(g)\omega$ for every $g\in G$. I've seen that, calling the inversion map $\beta$, we have $$L_{g}^{*}\beta^{*}(\omega)=(\beta \circ L_{g})^{*}\omega=(R_{g^{-1}} \circ \beta)^{*}\omega=\beta^{*}(c(g^{-1})\omega)=c(g^{-1})\beta^{*}\omega$$ so $\beta^{*}\omega$ might not be necessarily left invariant (for example. if $G$ is not connected). With a similar argument, I managed to prove that $\beta^{*}\omega$ is right invariant (but didn't see how to use that to my advantage). Another idea I had was to use the fact that the Haar integral is left and right invariant (which I was able to prove beforehand). Again, I don't see a clear way to get from that to the desired equality. Are any of my ideas on the right track?

The book I'm reading on the subject (''Compact Lie groups", by M. R. Sepanski) says that the argument used to prove the equation is similar to that of proving

$$\int_{G}f(gh)dg=\int_{G}f(g)dg$$ for any $h\in G$.

EDIT: I've seen written that this result can be used by proving uniqueness of the integral, i.e., that if the Haar integral can be determined by the properties I already proved, and the functional

$$J(f)=\int_{G}f(g^{-1})dg$$

verifies those properties, then $J$ is the Haar integral. I don't know how to prove either of those claims though.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Compact groups are unimodular, i.e. the modular function is identically one. To see this, we can start with the definition of the modular function
$$\mu_l(Bg)=c(g)\mu_l(B)$$
where $\mu_r$ is the left Haar measure and $B$ is a borel set of finite measure. It follows from this definition that $c:G\to\mathbb{R_+}$ is continuous (via some computation), positive (since $\mu_l$ is positive by definition), and a group homomorphism onto the positive reals with multiplication.

Furthermore, if $G$ is compact, then so is the image of $c$, which uniquely determines $c=1$. This in particular implies that $\mu_l$ is also right invariant (as a measure; the volume form may differ by a sign).

Comment: But what about $\det\colon O(2)\to \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, isn't that a possibility satisfying thoses hypotheses while not being constant?

Comment: Does your definition of the Haar measure include positivity? If so, it seems that $c$ would map into the positive reals.

Comment: So what would be happening is thar $R_{g}^{*}\omega$ is always equal to $c(g)\omega$, where $c(g)>0$? It seems reasonable to me, but I don't see a way of proving that.

Comment: We can say a bit more: the image of $c$ is a compact subgroup, and the only such subgroup is $\{1\}$.

Comment: I understand. Still, I'd need to prove that $c$ is a positive function. How should I go about that?

Comment: Implicitly, that would prove that $\omega$ is right-invariant too, wouldn't it?

Comment: I've added a bit more to the hint. Positivity is straightforward if you define $c$ in terms of measures.